# Scope for getJSON in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, getjson

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to manage scope when using getJSON.
So on a HTML page I have an unordered list to be filled with list items from a JSON file. The list is markup for a carousel.

HTML:
`<ul class="carousel"></ul>`

JS:

```
grabJSON : function() {
    $.getJSON('file.json', function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data.foo, function(k, v) {
            items.push('<li>' + v.bar + '</li>');
        }
        $('ul.carousel').append(items.join(''));
        // carousel action here
        $('ul.carousel').carouselFunction({
            // carousel options here
        });
    });
}
```

Currently, I have to place the carousel function within the getJSON function. If I make another function for setting up the carousel, I lose the scope within getJSON.

What is a preferred method of breaking this out so I can have a  `setupCarousel : function()` that is called from getJSON? Normally if I want to call a function from another function in an object I can just go `this.setupCarousel()`, however with nested scope I'm not sure how to handle this.

Also, outside of the getJSON function I do not have access to any of the elements that were appended. So I can access ul, but not any of the list items created while adding them from getJSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) call is asynchronous. So, if you do this:

```
thing.grabJSON();
do_some_other_stuff();
```

The `do_some_other_stuff` will be executed **before** the `$.getJSON` call finishes. You have to put everything inside the `$.getJSON` callback because that piece of code will be executed at some time in the future; the callback is free to pass any data it receives to other functions (as in Kishnore's answer) but code that is executed after `$.getJSON` (where *after* means after in the source code) can't depend on the `$.getJSON` call doing anything.

You could do something like this:

```
function buildCarousel(items) {
    $('ul.carousel').append(items.join(''));
    $('ul.carousel').carouselFunction({
        // carousel options here
    });
}

// ...

grabJSON : function(cb) {
    $.getJSON('file.json', function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data.foo, function(k, v) {
            items.push('<li>' + v.bar + '</li>');
        }
        cb(items);
    });
}

//...

thing.grabJSON(buildCarousel);
```

if you wanted to separate the `$.getJSON` from what needs to be done with that JSON. In this particular case, breaking it apart like the above is more busy work than real work but that sort of pattern (callbacks within callbacks, callbacks all the way down) is pretty common when dealing with AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the process going on. Still trying to get the handle on asynchronous callback behavior, and this definitely helps. Going to try to break it out like that.

Comment: Is there any way to call the object function (buildCarousel : function () {}) from the grabJSON, or does it have to be a function outside of it?

Comment: @xtine: `things.grabJSON(function(items) { things.buildCarousel(items) })`, another common pattern. There's also [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for binding a function to a specific `this` but you can't depend on that being available everywhere just yet.

Comment: Is there a name or reference for the things.grabJSON pattern?

Comment: @xtine: The anonymous function is a closure but I don't know of a name for that specific pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Did you Try something like this?

```
grabJSON : function() {
    $.getJSON('file.json', function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data.foo, function(k, v) {
            items.push('<li>' + v.bar + '</li>');
        }
        makeCarousel(items);
    });
}
//pass items to make carosuel function and use it this should solve your problem.
makeCarosuel: function(items) {
$('ul.carousel').append(items.join(''));
        // carousel action here
        $('ul.carousel').carouselFunction({
            // carousel options here
        });
}
```

Comment: You cannot call makeCarousel because it lacks the scope... it either has to be a outside function ( function makeCarousel() ), otherwise it won't recognize it.